# Catch multiple patterns

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match a string against multiple patterns and store the captures in an array.

The input can be one of the following:

```
-fnospacebetween
   -f textwithspacebefore
@nospacebetween
  @ textwithspacebefore
```

The regex should catch the string after `-f` or `@`. Spaces are allowed before the `-f` and `@`, also between `-f` or `@` and the string .
I thought about using a `|` splitted regex, but I don't know why it's not catching my input when I use the two regexes in a specific order.
The single case scenario, works as expected:

```
my $text = '@anystring' ;

if( $text =~ /^\s*\@\s*(\S*)/)
{
    print "\n $1";
}



my $text = '-fanystring' ;

if( $text =~ /^\s*-f\s*(\S*)/)
{
    print "\n $1";
}
```

But when I try use the two in one single regex, I get an `Use of unitialized...` :

```
my $text = '@anystring' ;

if( $text =~ /^\s*-f\s*(\S*)|^\s*\@\s*(\S*)/)
{
    print "\n $1";
}
```

But with this variant, it works correctly:

```
my $text = '@anystring' ;
if( $text =~ /^\s*\@\s*(\S*)|^\s*-f\s*(\S*)/)
{
    print "\n1:  $1";
}
```

Why it matches correctly when the order is switched?

Comment: @Borodin, sorry for the misslead, the `-` should be present only for the first 2 examples

Comment: Another solution is to use a branch reset: `/(?|^\s*\@\s*(\S*)|^\s*-f\s*(\S*))/`, but it makes sense when the patterns are completely different and you cannot "contract" them as in Borodin's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why it matches correctly when the order is switched?

This regex

```
/^\s*\@\s*(\S*)|^\s*-f\s*(\S*)/
```

will capture into either `$1` or `$2` depending on which alternative matched. But you are only ever printing `$1`, which is `undef` if it were the second alternative that matched

I suggest you use this instead, which has only one capture and uses an alternation on only the part of the pattern that is variable

```
/^\s*(?:\@|-f)\s*(\S*)/
```

Comment: Oh, I assumed it wll store the grouping from both in `$1`. Thank you for the suggestion, I will use that, because my solution would require additional checks on `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: Do you know where this case is documented?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Sorry, what case?

Comment: The `|` case. I want to read how the matched strings are captured when using multiple regexes separated with `|`.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Everything about Perl regexes is documented in [`perldoc perlre`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), but you won't find this mentioned explicitly. It's not *"multiple regexes separated with `|`"* it's *one regex pattern*. Captures in a regex are numbered in the order of appearance of their opening parentheses. That is described in `perlre`, but you won't find something saying that it doesn't change the rules if the regex pattern contains an alternation.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential problem with your regex is that it will also match

```
-f -fanother-flag
-@ -@another-flag
```

That is, `\S*` will match any following flag if there is no argument given to the first flag. Better to use `\s*([^-]?\S*)` if argument is optional, or `\s*([^-]\S*)` if mandatory. This still assumes the flag argument cannot begin with hyphen.